# Efficiently compute a sparse distance matrix for a subgraph, given a SciPy CSR distance matrix of the full graph in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse SciPy CSR distance matrix `D` that defines a graph `G` with vertices `V=[1,..,n]` with some large `n>100000`. Each row `i` of `D` has exactly `k` distances, inducing the `k` nearest neighbors of vertex `i`.

Furthermore, I have a subset `W` of the vertices `V`, which is about one order of magnitude smaller than `V`. From the distances `D`, I want to efficiently compute a sparse CSR distance matrix `E` for the vertices of `W`, with `k` neighbors each.

---

Simply slicing `D`, i.e., choosing `E=D[W,W]` does not work, because in general, the points of the subset will not even have a distance in `D`. With slicing, I end up with a matrix `E` that has somewhere between `0` and `k` entries in each row, where I wanted `k` exactly.

---

I could turn to some of the [compressed sparse graph routines](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.csgraph.html), e.g., the [Dijkstra](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csgraph.dijkstra.html#scipy.sparse.csgraph.dijkstra) algorithm. Then, I can compute:

> `E = dijkstra(csgraph=D, directed=False, indices=W)`

In principle, this gives me what I want, however, after this operation, `E` is an `ndarray` with a complete distance matrix for all vertices `W`, while I only wanted the `k` nearest neighbors. Obviously, I could pick those from the rows of `E` and toss everything away, but it's a waste of time computing these when I don't even use them.

The same problem arrives with the other available methods, like [Floyd Warshall](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csgraph.floyd_warshall.html#scipy.sparse.csgraph.floyd_warshall), [Bellman-Ford](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csgraph.bellman_ford.html#scipy.sparse.csgraph.bellman_ford), and [Johnson](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csgraph.johnson.html#scipy.sparse.csgraph.johnson), where I always get a full distance matrix for my subgraph.

---

I could try and build the matrix `E` row by row instead of in one go. This could in principle be achieved by fixing one vertex `i` in `W` and building and traversing a [breadth-first tree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csgraph.breadth_first_tree.html#scipy.sparse.csgraph.breadth_first_tree) rooted at `i` or by creating a [breadth-first order](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csgraph.breadth_first_order.html#scipy.sparse.csgraph.breadth_first_order) starting at `i`. Both would indicate the `k` closest elements from `W`, however, they would also order everything else after that, which is redundant in my application.

Along a similar line, I could, starting from `i` specifically compute the [shortest path](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csgraph.shortest_path.html#scipy.sparse.csgraph.shortest_path) to all other vertices in `W` and keep the `k` closest ones. However, depending on my graph layout and the position of `i`, I will likely have to repeat certain operations which will not result in an efficient algorithm.

---

Ideally, what I would like is an option to pass `W` and `k` to the [Dijkstra](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csgraph.dijkstra.html#scipy.sparse.csgraph.dijkstra) algorithm such that it stops building the all-shortest-paths for some vertex `i` as soon as it has encountered the `k`th element from `W`. Any suggestions on how to achieve this more efficiently than with what I have outlines above?

Comment: I don't know about these distance methods, but for basic calculations, matrix multuplication is the most 'efficient.  Even things like axis summation and indexing are done with it.

Comment: There's no way I can think of to calculate the `k` shortest distances on your kNN graph without calculating all of them. If you need the memory you could implement it as a two-pass solution, where you identify the `k` shortest paths by calculating everything in the first pass and then go through and fill a sparse array with the identified paths in the second pass. That's such a niche application though I don't know of any graph routines that have implemented it.